# TypeScript Generics with recursion, conditionals and matching Keys

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have the following type with 2 generic parameters:

```
type Result<INPUT, SPEC> = ...
```

The concrete type of `Result` depends on the various combinations of `INPUT` and `SPEC`.

How it should work:

```
if(INPUT extends {[key: string]: any}) {
  if(SPEC extends {[key: string]: any}) {
    Result = {[key in keyof INPUT]: SPEC[key] !== undefined
            ? Result<INPUT[key], SPEC[key]>
            : true
    }
  } else {
    // ...
  }
} else {
  // ...
}
```

In words:

- If `INPUT` and `SPEC` are objects, then `Result` should be an object with the keys of `INPUT`.
- For every key of `INPUT`: Check if `SPEC` contains the same key
- If `true`, then the value for this key is `Result<INPUT[key], SPEC[key]>`
- If `false`, then the value for this key is `true`

Additional Information:

- If `INPUT` and `SPEC` are objects, then `SPEC` is a subset of `INPUT`. This means: `INPUT` can be `{ foo: 42, bar: 42 }`, but `SPEC` is allowed to only contain `foo` or `bar` or both or be empty.

Is this somehow possible with TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, this type should do the trick:

```
export type Result<INPUT, SPEC> = INPUT extends object ? SPEC extends object ? {
    [K in keyof INPUT]: SPEC extends Record<K, infer SPECK> ?
        Result<INPUT[K], SPECK> :
        true
} : never : never;

// r is { foo: true; bar: never; goo: { a: never; b: true; }; }
type r = Result<{
    foo: number,
    bar: string,
    goo: { a: number; b: string }
}, { bar: number,  goo: { a: number }}>
```

The part you were probably missing is `SPEC extends Record<K, infer SPECK>`, this tests if the type extends a record with the key `K` and puts the type of that key in `SPECK`.

You were not explicit about what happens on the else branches (if either type parameters is not an object, so I put `never` there, but you can customize as you need)

Let me know if I did not get it 100% right, we can make adjustments as needed.

Comment: Btw. It looks like TypeScript knows what `extends Record<...>` means. You should be able to write this: `SPEC extends Record<K, any> ? Result<INPUT[K], SPEC[K]>`

Comment: @BenjaminM the compiler does not understand `Record` per se it understands the mapped type underlying it and figures out the relationship between the keys. But you are right, your way works too 